# Trying to write an embedded resource as a stream of bytes but they are always null

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, arrays, nullreferenceexception

so i am trying to write an exe file in my resources and this is the method that i am using: i add the file as a resource, then i add this code to the **Resources.Designer.cs**

```
internal static byte[] exefile
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("exe-file-name", resourceCulture);
            return ((byte[])(obj));
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GetSubExe()
    {
        return exefile;
    }
```

then i write this into my main form source code **From1.cs** in the event that i want:

```
string tempExeName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Creating.exe");

        using (FileStream fsDst = new FileStream(tempExeName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = Resources.GetSubExe();

            fsDst.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(kryptonTextBox4.Text);
        createpatch(kryptonTextBox3.Text,kryptonTextBox4.Text,patchname,path);
        Application.DoEvents();

        File.Delete("Creating.exe");
```

When i run the code i always get a **NullReferenceException** on this line:

```
fsDst.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `return ((byte[])(obj))` line. My bet is that `obj` will be null. You'll need to go through the documentation for `ResourceManager.GetObject` and ensure that you've set everything up properly.

Comment: Check your Resources.Designer.cs. It could be that `exe-file-name` is imported under the name `exe_file_name` (i.e. with underscores).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy i am sorry i didn't reply i lost connexion for the past few days, i will check and will be back with some feedback
@ AlexD the file name is only temp here and it's one word in my project so i am sure it's good.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy first of ll sorry for double post, BreakPointing that line will not be executed, am i calling the method right ?